# Can the package "caption" be used with KOMAScript classes?

Tags: captions, koma-script, incompatibility

Is the LaTeX package `caption` compatible with KOMA-Script classes like `scrreprt`?

(I did not find anything about that in the KOMA-Script manual, but as KOMA-Script redefines a lot for the floats and captions, I wonder if there might be problems.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See section 5.4 of the [caption manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/caption/caption-eng.pdf) for an overview of the interplay between `KOMA-script` and `caption`. Quoting the "Side effects":

> The optional argument of
>   `\setcapwidth` is not supported and
>   will be ignored if used in conjunction
>   with the `caption` package.
>   Furthermore the `KOMA-Script` options
>   `tablecaptionabove` &
>   `tablecaptionbelow` and the commands
>   `\captionabove` & `\captionbelow` are
>   stronger than the `position=` setting
>   offered by the `caption` package.

Comment: Please note that the version 3.1 of the caption package is not adapted to the new features of KOMA-Script3 yet. So currently using \DeclareCaptionType is not recommended since it does not integrate the new floating environments into the new KOMA-Script features, better use \DeclareNewTOC instead. Futhermore \captionaboveof and \captionbelowof are not supported by the caption package yet, and the caption package is not aware of the tocbasic package yet. (This will change in version 3.2 of the caption package.)

Comment: BTW: As a general rule one can say: If there is a solution offered by KOMA-Script, and a one offered by the caption package, better use the KOMA-Script one.

Answer (score -1):

At the start of figure or table, KOMA redefines `\caption` to be either `\captionabove` or `\captionbelow`.  This forces them to use the caption package `\caption`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{caption}

\makeatletter
\let\x@caption\caption% original (caption package) \caption
\renewcommand{\captionabove}{\captionsetup{position=above}\x@caption}%
\renewcommand{\captionbelow}{\captionsetup{position=below}\x@caption}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\begin{figure}
\captionsetup{singlelinecheck=false}
\caption{should be left justified}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: You absolutely wrong. First of all `memoir` *is not* a KOMA-Script class. Furthermore, all KOMA-Script classes have and use `\captionabove` and `\captionbelow` and you can configure them using option `captions`. And you do not need to redefine `\captionabove` or `\captionbelow`.

Comment: @Schweinebacke - Ah, that explains why it doesn't work with memoir.