# Writing a multi-page table on a custom document class

Tags: captions, longtable

I am currently writing an article for submission in a journal, which has a custom document class. I have a very long table, so a `longtable` is needed in this case, but it contradicts the formatting guidelines set inside the document class (specifically the custom caption command). Is there a "long" version of `tabular` so that I can use the specific commands of the `table` environment of the required document class?

For reference, I am using `nrc1` document class, and it has custom caption command `\topcaption`.

MWC:

```
\documentclass[preprint]{nrc1}
\usepackage{booktabs,longtable}

\begin{document}
\title{The Title}
\author{The Author}
\address{The Address}

\maketitle

Insert text here.

\begin{table}[!h]
\topcaption{Caption Title }
\begin{tabular}{crrr}
\toprule
ColA & ColB & ColC & ColD \\
\midrule
a1 & b1 & c1 & d1\\
a2 & b2 & c2 & d2\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\label{tab:tab1}
\end{table}



\begin{longtable}{crrrrrrrr}
\caption{Short Title.}\\
\toprule
C1 & C2 & C3 & C4 & C5 & C6 & C7 & C8 & C9 \\
\midrule\endfirsthead

\toprule
C1 & C2 & C3 & C4 & C5 & C6 & C7 & C8 & C9 \\
\midrule\endhead

\midrule\multicolumn{9}{r}{(continued on next page)}\endfoot

\bottomrule\endlastfoot

$a1$ & xxx.xx & xxx.xx & --& --& --& --& --& xx.xxxx \\
$a2$ & xxx.xx & xxx.xx & --& --& --& --& --& xx.xxxx\\
$a3$ & xxx.xx & xxx.xx & --& --& --& --& --& xx.xxxx \\
$a4$ & xxx.xx & xxx.xx & --& --& --& --& --& xx.xxxx \\
$a5$ & xxx.xx & xxx.xx & --& --& --& --& --& xx.xxxx \\
$a6$ & xxx.xx & xxx.xx & --& --& --& --& --& xx.xxxx \midrule

$a1$ & xxx.xx & xxx.xx & --& --& --& --& --& xx.xxxx \\
$a2$ & xxx.xx & xxx.xx & --& --& --& --& --& xx.xxxx\\
$a3$ & xxx.xx & xxx.xx & --& --& --& --& --& xx.xxxx \\
$a4$ & xxx.xx & xxx.xx & --& --& --& --& --& xx.xxxx \\
$a5$ & xxx.xx & xxx.xx & --& --& --& --& --& xx.xxxx \\
$a6$ & xxx.xx & xxx.xx & --& --& --& --& --& xx.xxxx \midrule


$a1$ & xxx.xx & xxx.xx & --& --& --& --& --& xx.xxxx \\
$a2$ & xxx.xx & xxx.xx & --& --& --& --& --& xx.xxxx\\
$a3$ & xxx.xx & xxx.xx & --& --& --& --& --& xx.xxxx \\
$a4$ & xxx.xx & xxx.xx & --& --& --& --& --& xx.xxxx \\
$a5$ & xxx.xx & xxx.xx & --& --& --& --& --& xx.xxxx \\
$a6$ & xxx.xx & xxx.xx & --& --& --& --& --& xx.xxxx \midrule

$a1$ & xxx.xx & xxx.xx & --& --& --& --& --& xx.xxxx \\
$a2$ & xxx.xx & xxx.xx & --& --& --& --& --& xx.xxxx\\
$a3$ & xxx.xx & xxx.xx & --& --& --& --& --& xx.xxxx \\
$a4$ & xxx.xx & xxx.xx & --& --& --& --& --& xx.xxxx \\
$a5$ & xxx.xx & xxx.xx & --& --& --& --& --& xx.xxxx \\
$a6$ & xxx.xx & xxx.xx & --& --& --& --& --& xx.xxxx \midrule

$a1$ & xxx.xx & xxx.xx & --& --& --& --& --& xx.xxxx \\
$a2$ & xxx.xx & xxx.xx & --& --& --& --& --& xx.xxxx\\
$a3$ & xxx.xx & xxx.xx & --& --& --& --& --& xx.xxxx \\
$a4$ & xxx.xx & xxx.xx & --& --& --& --& --& xx.xxxx \\
$a5$ & xxx.xx & xxx.xx & --& --& --& --& --& xx.xxxx \\
$a6$ & xxx.xx & xxx.xx & --& --& --& --& --& xx.xxxx \midrule

$a1$ & xxx.xx & xxx.xx & --& --& --& --& --& xx.xxxx \\
$a2$ & xxx.xx & xxx.xx & --& --& --& --& --& xx.xxxx\\
$a3$ & xxx.xx & xxx.xx & --& --& --& --& --& xx.xxxx \\
$a4$ & xxx.xx & xxx.xx & --& --& --& --& --& xx.xxxx \\
$a5$ & xxx.xx & xxx.xx & --& --& --& --& --& xx.xxxx \\
$a6$ & xxx.xx & xxx.xx & --& --& --& --& --& xx.xxxx 

\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Please provide a link to the class and code for a minimal document we can use to reproduce the issue. You cannot use `table` with a multipage anything because `table` is a float and floats are boxes which can't contain page breaks. You could split the table manually. Or you can use one of the multipage packages (such as `longtable`) outside a float. But multipage floats are almost a contradiction in terms.

Comment: Updated the post @cfr. Also, the `nrc1` class is already pre-installed (I think). Re `table`, I am aware that it's a float, but manually splitting the table is cumbersome when you are still editing the whole manuscript.

I am thinking of instead customizing the caption format, but maybe there are alternative ways not resorting to creating too complex commands that will contradict the document class.

Comment: The use of \topcaption indicates that nrcl may be a KOMA variant.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22177/can-the-package-caption-be-used-with-komascript-classes/383025#383025

Comment: Ah, yes. Part of the `nrc` package? @JohnKormylo Parasitic on `article`, it seems.

Comment: I like the copyright note at the beginning of the file :-)