# Tufte class: Force caption to be below table

Tags: tables, captions, tufte

I am using the tufte-class to write a report. I have some good sized tables with text in the cells with the table being large enough to go into the margins. This is OK with me. However, the caption's margin placement "crowds out" the wide table so it doesn't fit in the page.

Can I force the caption to just sit below the table, without wrapping, allowing full usage of the page by the table itself?

```
\documentclass[nobib,american,justified, notoc, symmetric]{tufte-book}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[pangram]{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{Some awesome table we have here. Why am I inside the table float?}
\setfloatalignment{b}% aligns to bottom
\begin{tabular}{|p{2.9cm}|p{4.1cm}|p{3.8cm}|p{4.6cm}|}
\hline
\textbf{a} & \textbf{b} & \textbf{c} & \textbf{d} \\ \hline
\Blindtext[1][1] & \Blindtext[1][1] & \Blindtext[1][1] & \Blindtext[1][1] \\ \hline
\Blindtext[1][1] & \Blindtext[1][1] & \Blindtext[1][1] & \Blindtext[1][1] \\ \hline
\Blindtext[1][1] & \Blindtext[1][1] & \Blindtext[1][1] & \Blindtext[1][1] \\ \hline
\Blindtext[1][1] & \Blindtext[1][1] & \Blindtext[1][1] & \Blindtext[1][1] \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Using `\begin{table*} ... \end{table*}` (with an asterisk) will give you a full-width table and the caption will be placed above or below the table. Does that do what you want?

Comment: Use \captionbelow to put the caption below the tabular (and NOT in the marginpar area).  See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22177/can-the-package-caption-be-used-with-komascript-classes  Finally, \setfloatalignment[b] is supposed to move the float to the bottom of the page.  In order to do that, you also need to increase \bottomfraction.  \begin{table*}[b] works better.