# Empty captions with KOMA-script

Tags: captions, koma-script

I like captions to normally have a colon, but not when the caption is empty. This is something that the package `caption` does automatically, so

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \caption{Test}
  \caption{}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

yields "Figure 1: Test / Figure 2".
That is all very fine, but I want to use KOMA captions without the `caption` package, and then I get "Figure 1: Test / Figure 2:" with the extra colon at the end.

Here is my best try in fixing this, but it doesn't work. How can I do instead?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\scr@@makesinglelinecaption}[3]{%
    \usekomafont{caption}{\strut\ignorespaces
      #1{{\usekomafont{captionlabel}{#2\ifthenelse{\isempty{#3}}{}{\captionformat}}}}%
      \ignorespaces #3\unskip}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \caption{Test}
  \caption{}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: See akso https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22177/can-the-package-caption-be-used-with-komascript-classes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your test doesn't work as KOMA doesn't pass an empty argument, it contains (for an unknown reason) \ignorespaces, so you should test for this:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{expl3,xpatch}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\scr@@makesinglelinecaption{\captionformat}
 {\tl_if_eq:nnF {\ignorespaces}{#3}{\captionformat}}{}{\fail}
\ExplSyntaxOff

%\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \caption{Test}
  \caption{}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I guessed there was "something" there anyway, but I didn't know what. Would have liked some is-essentially-empty predicate (maybe there is?) that would work even if the innards changed.

Comment: You could put the argument in a box and measure its width - actually now that you mention it: this patch will only work if you use the `oneline` option, without it the singlelinecaption is not used.  On the whole it is probably better to patch \@@makecaption, or to make a feature request ...

Comment: Right. Normally an empty caption will be a oneliner, so that's why I went there. It doesn't work with captions=nooneline, but that's not a problem for me.

Comment: Actually now it didn't work for me in an actual more complicated environment. How can I log what is in `#3` then? I naively tried `\typeout{#3}`.

Comment: \typeout should work, put it before the \tl_if_eq.

Comment: Oh, now I see it does work for the simple example. When it didn't work in my actual file I assumed I was doing it wrong.  It was interference with `hyperref` that made it not work. I've tried just adding that to the small example and don't get it to work, regardless of loading order. So now I want to amend my question (or maybe make a new one)...

Comment: The `\ignorespaces` is from the definition of `\@caption` in the LaTeX kernel. KOMA-Script does not redefine `\caption` or `\@caption`. And the `\ignorespaces` could make sense, e.g., to tolerate a line break after `\caption{`.