# Caption placement for figure on the right

Tags: captions, wrapfigure

I often want to place figures on the right and let the text flow around it using wrapfig. For small figures this is nearly always an issue because the caption will be smushed together and extend over textwidth edge. Is there any way to fix this (e.g. maybe place it under Fig.)?

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.13\textwidth}
  \vspace{-25pt}
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=0.13\textwidth]{img/.../sdf_layerAndFileFormat.png}
    \label{fig:metadata}
  \end{center}
    \vspace{-35pt}
  \caption{metadata}
      \vspace{-15pt}
\end{wrapfigure}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  At least some document classes define the appearance of a caption.  Therefore, we need to know what document class you're using.  For best results, please provide a brief file that exhibits the result you show, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}.

Comment: \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrreprt}

Comment: The requirements to answer your question is not fulfilled yet, but if you cant post your brief code, all we can suggest that, you should increase the width of your figure and caption will be fitted smoothly. Greetings :)

Comment: You can either enlarge the figure width, or reduce the caption font size. You cannot insist on both!

Comment: "e.g. maybe place it under Fig.", you mean just in this figure, or all the document figures?

Comment: Alas, KOMA is not compatible with the caption package (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22177/can-the-package-caption-be-used-with-komascript-classes), which can easily fix the hanging indentation.