# KOMAscript - proper captions without caption and float?

Tags: floats, captions, koma-script

A KOMAscript based template a few years old needs some updates because versions and compatibilities have changed (eg. `filecontents` not requiring an extra package anymore, etc.). In this process I tried to get rid of warnings and/or packages for which there is already functionality in KOMAscript. `float` and `caption` are the last packages to resist.

The requirements are

1. wanting to get rid of float [H] (the only reason the `float` package is used)
2. have captions aligned to the left below tables / figures
3. optionally there might be some remark about the table / figure origin including a `\cite` between table/figure and caption
4. links from ListOf should go to the table/figure no the caption itself to be useful

[image: Captions with caption/float]

Here's the code for the caption/float based version:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\setkomafont{captionlabel}{\bfseries}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[
    singlelinecheck=false,
]{caption}

\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    citestyle=authoryear,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @Book{Mittal2013,
        title     = {Netcentric System of Systems Engineering with DEVS Unified Process},
        author    = {Mittal, Saurabh and Martín, José L. R.},
        publisher = {CRC Press},
        year      = {2013},
        series    = {System of systems engineering},
        isbn      = {978-1-4398-2707-9},
    }
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[
    hidelinks,
    breaklinks=true
]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    bookmarksopen=true,
    bookmarksopenlevel=3,
    bookmarksnumbered=true,
    linktoc=all,
}

\begin{document}
\listoftables
\newpage

\lipsum[1-4]
\begin{table}[H]
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
            \hline
            \textbf{Category} & \textbf{Diagram type} \\
            \hline
            Structure diagrams & Class diagrams \\ \cline{2-2}
            & Component diagrams \\ \cline{2-2}
            & Object diagrams \\ \cline{2-2}
            & Composite structure diagrams \\ \cline{2-2}
            & Deployment diagrams \\ \cline{2-2}
            & Package diagrams \\ \hline
            Behavior diagrams & Activity diagrams \\ \cline{2-2}
            & Use case diagrams \\ \cline{2-2}
            & State diagrams \\ \hline
            Interaction diagrams & Sequence diagrams \\ \cline{2-2}
            & Collaboration diagrams \\ \cline{2-2}
            & Interaction overview diagrams \\ \cline{2-2}
            & Timing diagrams \\     \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \captionbelow*{Based on \protect\cite[p.~11]{Mittal2013}}
        \captionbelow[UML diagram types]{UML diagram types\\ \lipsum[1-1]}
    \end{center}
\end{table}
\lipsum[5-5]

\cleardoublepage
\newpage

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

And here is the code trying to achieve the same but only by using KOMAscript:

```
\documentclass[
    captions=nooneline,
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    citestyle=authoryear,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @Book{Mittal2013,
        title     = {Netcentric System of Systems Engineering with DEVS Unified Process},
        author    = {Mittal, Saurabh and Martín, José L. R.},
        publisher = {CRC Press},
        year      = {2013},
        series    = {System of systems engineering},
        isbn      = {978-1-4398-2707-9},
    }
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[
    hidelinks,
    breaklinks=true
]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    bookmarksopen=true,
    bookmarksopenlevel=3,
    bookmarksnumbered=true,
    linktoc=all,
}

\begin{document}
\listoftables
\newpage

\lipsum[1-4]
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
            \hline
            \textbf{Category} & \textbf{Diagram type} \\
            \hline
            Structure diagrams & Class diagrams \\ \cline{2-2}
            & Component diagrams \\ \cline{2-2}
            & Object diagrams \\ \cline{2-2}
            & Composite structure diagrams \\ \cline{2-2}
            & Deployment diagrams \\ \cline{2-2}
            & Package diagrams \\ \hline
            Behavior diagrams & Activity diagrams \\ \cline{2-2}
            & Use case diagrams \\ \cline{2-2}
            & State diagrams \\ \hline
            Interaction diagrams & Sequence diagrams \\ \cline{2-2}
            & Collaboration diagrams \\ \cline{2-2}
            & Interaction overview diagrams \\ \cline{2-2}
            & Timing diagrams \\     \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
    Based on \cite[p.~11]{Mittal2013}
    \captionbelowof{table}[UML diagram types]{UML diagram types\\ \lipsum[1-1]}
\end{minipage}

\lipsum[5-5]

\cleardoublepage
\newpage

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

It mostly works but links are pointing to the caption instead of the table.

Comment: The hypcap package raises hyperlinks to the top of figure, although I'm not sure if it is KOMA compatible either.  See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22177/can-the-package-caption-be-used-with-komascript-classes/383025?r=SearchResults&s=2|30.8253#383025

Comment: What error message do you get when using a recent version of the caption package?

Comment: Apparently the error I got was due to some issue I can't reproduce. Tested the MWE and my real document with a non-bounded version and it works. Corrected the question accordingly.