Center figure caption with line breaks in scrbook class
I need the caption of my figures (actually pgf plots) to be centered with the (sub)figures. But keep the formatting as it is (left aligned and hanging after the Figure label).
Please note: I know there are already many questions regarding this issue - however none of the solutions worked in my case (so far).

\documentclass[
12pt,
a4paper,
]{scrbook}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption} 
\setkomafont{captionlabel}{\usekomafont{caption}\bfseries\rmfamily}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=6cm]{example-image-a}
        \caption*{(b)}
        \end{minipage}
    \hspace{2cm}
        \begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=6cm]{example-image-b}
        \caption*{(b)}
        \end{minipage}
    \caption[caption for toc]{Caption of\\ 
        (a) figure one (here is a longer text)\\
        (b) figure two (here is a longer text)\\
        \textit{text text text}}
    \end{center}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}


Somewhat related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22177/can-the-package-caption-be-used-with-komascript-classes  Although I'm not sure that what you want is achievable usinng only caption package options.

You don't need to guess the width. Using varwidth will fool LaTeX into thinking that the caption is shorter than the text width, so it will center it.
\documentclass[
  12pt,
  a4paper,
]{scrbook}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\setkomafont{captionlabel}{\usekomafont{caption}\bfseries\rmfamily}
\usepackage{varwidth,calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering

\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{}
\end{subfigure}\hspace{2cm}% <--- don't forget
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
  \caption{}
\end{subfigure}

\caption[caption for toc]{%
  \begin{varwidth}[t]{\textwidth-\widthof{\textbf{\figurename\ \thefigure:} }}
    Caption of\\
    (a) figure one (here is a longer text)\\
    (b) figure two (here is a longer text)\\
    \textit{text text text}
  \end{varwidth}}

\end{figure}

\end{document}

Since subcaption loads caption, it makes no sense to load captions later.
Using textwidth=6cm produces overfull boxes, because 0.3\textwidth is less than 6cm; moreover, using subfigure allows to produce the letter without guessing.

If your document uses \setcapwidth, you should use
\csname cap@width\csname

instead of \textwidth in the argument to varwidth.

You can restrain the width of the caption box with \setcapwidth, so that it will appear centered.
Note that \setcapwidth is defined by scrbook and allows normally an optional argument to set the justification of the box. But that optional argument will be ignored in your case, as you're using the caption package (see the  manual of the caption package, section 5.4, KOMA - Script: scrartcl, scrreprt, and scrbook).
Example:
\documentclass[
12pt,
a4paper,
]{scrbook}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\setkomafont{captionlabel}{\usekomafont{caption}\bfseries\rmfamily}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=6cm]{example-image-a}
        \caption*{(b)}
        \end{minipage}
    \hspace{2cm}
        \begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=6cm]{example-image-b}
        \caption*{(b)}
      \end{minipage}
    \setcapwidth{0.5\linewidth}
    \caption[caption for toc]{Caption of\\
        (a) figure one (here is a longer text)\\
        (b) figure two (here is a longer text)\\
        \textit{text text text}}
    \end{center}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}



Thank you - this is however not quite was I need since this breaks the line again (since the caption width is restrained)
